# Loading sql file from sql file in mysql

Tags: mysql, windows

I have a master sql file that I called in the mysql command prompt:

```
 mysql>source /tmp/folder/masterFile.sql
```

In the masterFile.sql, I have some source files:

```
source players.sql
source teams.sql
```

The problem is that it gives me this error message saying that it can find the file.

```
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'players.sql \* to create players table *\', error: 2
```

The masterFile.sql and the other files are in the same directory.

Comment: It looks like you have comments in your masterfile.sql but you mixed up the comment syntax, using `\* *\ ` where you should have used `/* */`.

Comment: I removed it and it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note-1: It is better to use the full path of the SQL file file.sql.

Note-2: Use -R and --triggers to keep the routines and triggers of original database. They are not copied by default.

Note-3 You may have to create the (empty) database from mysql if it doesn't exist already and the exported SQL don't contain CREATE DATABASE (exported with --no-create-db or -n option), before you can import it.